# Xpath help to Find Unique value

Tags: html, xpath

I want to find the first tr tag with PONumber: text. I am not able to do that. Any help? I can find it using the `//table/tbody/tr/td[contains(text(),'PONumber')]` but it gives 2 objects. I want to find the first one only.

```
<tr>    
<td class="clsLabel" align="right">   PONumber:  </td>
<td class="clsInput">         PN659      </td>
</tr>    
<tr>    
<td class="clsLabel" align="right">   PreviousPONumber:  </td>
<td class="clsInput"/>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use following xpath to find exact object which you want

```
//tr/td[normalize-space(.)='PONumber:']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like

`(//tr/td[contains(text(),'PONumber')])[1]`

so put the xpath in brackets and with `[1]` you can specifiy to only return the first entry. Otherwise you could also use something like:

`//tr/td[contains(text(),'PONumber') and not(contains(text(),'Previous'))]`

so "Previous" will be excluded from the search results

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the XPath result to return only the first matched by using `[1]` :

```
(//table/tbody/tr/td[contains(.,'PONumber')])[1]
```